# Why haven't the remaining TRSAs been converted to Class C airspace?

Tags: faa, airspace

The communication and radar equipment is already in place to provide radar services. ATC staff them. It seems like the biggest investment to get them converted to class C is charting. Why haven't they been converted in the 25 years since the airspace reclassification?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Terminal Radar Service Area (TRSA) and what are its operational requirements?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/22134/what-is-a-terminal-radar-service-area-trsa-and-what-are-its-operational-requir)

Comment: @Dave Not even close to a duplicate.

Comment: while the question its self is not (in terms of the direct ask). The answer ultimately covers this question hence the dupe marking. If no one else feels it is a dupe it will remain open, it takes a few dupe markings before a question is closed as a permanent dupe.

Comment: @Dave That answer is 10% of what I'm looking for at best.

Comment: If that's true @MattYoung then I would suggest expanding your question. If others feel that the answer is covered and you don't there must be a way to express that.

Answer (score 2):

Class C airspace is established by a rulemaking procedure (i.e., Notice of Proposed Rulemaking, comments, publication, etc.).  TRSAs are not established by rulemaking action.

**From FAA JO 7210.3Z- Facility Operations and Administration -para. 11-1-3 & 4**

***Class C:***

> Class  C  airspace  **must  be  officially**  **designated  by**
>   **airspace action** in 14 CFR Part 71 and is established
>   solely to define the airspace in which **all aircraft** are
>   subject  to  operating  rules  and  equipment  requirements specified in 14 CFR Part 91.[emphasis is mine]

***TRSA:***

> TRSAs 
>   **are not officially designated 
>   by airspace**
>   action and were established solely to define an area
>   within which a separation service will be provided.
>   [empasis is mine]

Within a TRSA the (vfr) pilot **is not required** to participate.  However, within Class C airspace a (vfr) pilot **is required** to participate.

***It is not as simple as a charting issue:***

If a Radar Facility Manager wants to change a TRSA and make it Class C airspace a staff study must be done and proper justification has to be documented and approved. See Class C Airspace Processing (staff study protocol) [FAA Order 7400.2L - Procedures for Handling Airspace Matters - para: 16-3-1](http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/7400.2L_Bsc_w_Chg1_dtd_10-12-17.pdf)

Since the implementation of Regulatory Class C airspace requires more ATC involvement to provide the service (Class C service) and requires mandatory participation on the part of vfr pilots, the process can be a significant challenge that has to be clearly needed for the area in question and fully justified with consideration of public comments, etc., and a variety of other procedural steps to comply with rulemaking procedures.

In short, unless the Facility Manager (for that area) has determined that a higher level of air traffic control  is necessary for safety/service, etc., and then provides justification and considers comments from the public (who may not want the additional restrictions of Class C), changing a TRSA into Class C airspace won't happen.